# Random variables and distribution

Tags: probability

I have a problem understanding the following:

$X$ and $Y$ are independent vatiables with
$$P(X = i) = P(Y = i) = \frac{1}{2^i}. \quad i = 1, 2, \cdots$$
Now the book says$ P(X< i)= \dfrac{1}{2^i}$. I really do not get that… Would be nice if you could help maybe.

Best
KingDingeling

Comment: What is $Y$ doing here ? And the $\text{cdf}$ cannot be a decreasing function.

Comment: $Y$ has nothing to do with the question. and what was given in the question is Probabiltiy mass function (pmf), not cdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(X < i)+P(X \geq i) = 1 $$
$P(X \geq i) = 1-P(X < i)$

$P(X<i) = P(X=1)+P(X=2)+......P(X=i-1)$

$= \dfrac{1}{2^1} +\dfrac{1}{2^2}+.....\dfrac{1}{2^{i-1}}$. The series is in Goemetric Progression. Calculating its value, you get

$=\dfrac{1}{2}. \dfrac{1-(\dfrac{1}{2})^{i-1}}{1-\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$= 1-(\dfrac{1}{2})^{i-1}$. Solving for $P(X \geq i)$, you get

$P(X \geq i) = 1-P(X < i) = 1-[1-(\dfrac{1}{2})^{i-1}]  = (\dfrac{1}{2})^{i-1} = \dfrac{1}{2^{i-1}}$

Comment: Thank you very much, very kind.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: @Narenda I just don't understand why you have the 1/2 in front when you calculate the value... I thought with the formula we must take the fraction and then -1 because we start at 1 and not zero. Sorry if I ask more stupid questions..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression. Try to understand the formula for sum of elements which are in GP.

Comment: that's odd.. I have the same formula, but I get 1-(1/2)^i-1 out of it..

Comment: Yes you are correct. You'll get $1 - \dfrac{1}{2^{i-1}}$

Comment: Thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a typo.

$P(X > i) =1-\sum_{k=1}^{k=i}P(X =k)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{k=i}{P(X = k)} 
= 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{k=i}{\frac{1}{2^k}}= \frac{1}{2^i}$

Comment: $P(X \geq i) = \dfrac {1}{2^i}$

Comment: @NarendraDeconda Thx! I reedit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Travis, kind of you to answer so quickly. Can you please explain the last step, the transition of the sum? That would be really nice :)

Also how do you get to your solution for P(X>=i)? Why ist that the same as P(X=i)?

Sorry for this stupid questions..

Comment: Just a geometric progression.

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ...  = 1$$

$$ P(X >= i ) = \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}$$

Comment: Thx :) Appreciate it.